# how to have other ini files for php 5.4 windows

Tags: php, windows, php-ini

Sorry but that is just about it

**Ihave tried many things**

> *Thanks*

[image: phpinfo]

> > I would like to split php.ini file into chunks of ini files 
> >     **E.G php.ini mysqli.ini**

**Leran using this *Apache directive***

```
PHPIniDir
```

Comment: Explain a bit more.. question in unclear

Comment: may i know wat ar you doing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Split your php.ini as you wish, save it to some directory, then add to Apache config file:

```
SetEnv PHP_INI_SCAN_DIR d:\customdir
```

then, Apache will scan for all `ini` files in the directory `d:\customdir` and use them.

Or try `php_value include_path "d:\custom"` in your `.htaccess`.

Comment: read dir But it did not read the ini file

Comment: @RamiJamleh try `php_value include_path "d:\custom"` in you `.htaccess`.